# Gcode sender install and use

Tags: software-installation

So new to Ubuntu and I am sure I am missing the simple/basic commands and understanding. But cannot not seem to find what I am missing online via search. Installed on a number of laptops for crypto currency mining and working nicely.

Trying to use for a CNC machine in this case. Using 18.04. I have downloaded the gcode sender package (ugsplatform-linux) and extracted to folder. When I double click the ugsplatform file it opens like a txt file. Not sure how to 'Run' or execute the file and get the software open. When I open terminal and go the correct folder and enter in 'ugsplatform', I get the command not found message.

Thx for any assistance.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Please try to call it with path to current folder - `./ugsplatform`. Which version of UGS do you use? What was its download URL?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify current folder (`./`) path when calling executable.

Use command below

```
./ugsplatform
```

and if you get any error output please add it to the original question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1292600/edit).